# How to move the game on to the background in pygame in python 2.7?

Tags: python-2.7, pygame

SO what happened is that when I run the code it shows the background but after that the next part does not get displayed in the pygame window.I am new to python and want to fix this problem. Here is the code:

```
import random
import pygame
import sys
from pygame.locals import *


bif="boring.jpg"


pygame.init()
screen_size = (224, 225)
screen=pygame.display.set_mode( screen_size, 0, 32)
background = pygame.image.load(bif).convert()
mouse_c = pygame.image.load(bif).convert_alpha()

while (True):
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            sys.exit()

    screen.blit(background, (0,0) )
    pygame.display.update()

print "Hello ! Welcome to the Guessing GAME !"
print "Please Guess a Number Between 1-10"
computernum = random.randint (1,10)
Guess_1 = input("My First Guess is :")
if Guess_1==computernum:
    print "Correct"
    print "retype the winning number"
    print "On to the next level..."
else:
    print "Sorry, Try Again"
    print "You Have Two Guesses Remaining"
if Guess_1 > computernum:
    print "Too high"
if Guess_1 < computernum:
    print "Too Low"

Guess_2 = input("My Second Guess Is :")

if Guess_2 == computernum:
    print "Correct!"
    print "retype the winning number"
    print "On to the next level..."
else:
    print "Sorry, Try Again"
    print "You Have One More Guess"
if Guess_2 > computernum:
    print "Too high"
if Guess_2 < computernum:
    print "Too Low"

Guess_3=input("My Last Guess Is :")

if Guess_3==computernum:
    print "Correct!"
    print "On to the next level..."
else:
    print " You Lose"
    computernum = str (computernum)
    print "The Number Was "+ computernum
    THE_END = input("Press enter Key to Exit")

    if  THE_END==(32):
        sys.exit (0)






import random
import sys
print "Please Guess a Number Between 1-15"
computernum = random.randint (1,15)

Guess_1 = input ("My First Guess is :")

if Guess_1==computernum:
    print "Correct"
    print "RETYPE WINNING NUMBER"
    print "NEXT LEVEL"
else:
    print "Sorry, Try Again"
    print "You Have Two Guesses Remaining"
if Guess_1 > computernum:
    print "Too high"
if Guess_1 < computernum:
    print "Too Low"

Guess_2 = input ("My Second Guess Is :")

if Guess_2==computernum:
    print "Correct"
    print "RETYPE WINNING NUMBER"
    print "NEXT LEVEL"
else:
    print "Sorry, Try Again"
    print "You Have One More Guess"
if Guess_2 > computernum:
    print "Too high"
if Guess_2 < computernum:
    print "Too Low"

Guess_3 = input ("My Last Guess Is :")

if Guess_3==computernum:
    print "Correct!"
    print "NEXT LEVEL"
else:
    print " You Lose"
    computernum = str (computernum)
    print "The Number Was "+ computernum
    THE_END = input("Press enter Key to Exit")

    if  THE_END==(32):
            sys.exit (0)


import random
import sys
print "Please Guess a Number Between 1-20"
computernum = random.randint (1,20)

Guess_1 = input ("My First Guess is :")

if Guess_1==computernum:
    print "Correct"
    print "You WIN!"
    print "Press Any Key to Exit"
    input=()
    sys.exit
else:
    print "Sorry, Try Again"
    print "You Have Two Guesses Remaining"
if Guess_1 > computernum:
    print "Too high"
if Guess_1 < computernum:
    print "Too Low"

Guess_2 = input ("My Second Guess Is :")

if Guess_2==computernum:
    print "Correct"
    print "You WIN!"
    print "Press Any Key to Exit"
    input=()
    sys.exit (0)
else:
    print "Sorry, Try Again"
    print "You Have One More Guess"
if Guess_2 > computernum:
    print "Too high"
if Guess_2 < computernum:
    print "Too Low"

Guess_3 = input ("My Last Guess Is :")

if Guess_3==computernum:
    print "Correct!"
    print "You WIN"
    THE_END = input("Press enter Key to Exit")

    if  THE_END==(32):
            sys.exit (0)

else:
    print " You Lose"
    computernum = str (computernum)
    print "The Number Was "+ computernum
    THE_END = input("Press Enter Key to Exit")

    if  THE_END==():
            sys.exit (0)
```

Comment: Your `while` loop will stop anything below it from running as it is an infinite loop. Try getting rid of the lines `while...` to `sys.exit()` and then remove the indent on the `screen.blit..` and `pygame.display...` Also, just so you're under no illusions, none of the print statements will appear on your pygame window, they'll go to your console instead.

Comment: Also, you should really use `raw_input` rather than `input` as you can expose your system to potentially malicious inputs. Edit: just seen `input=()` should really be `raw_input()`.

Comment: `print` will output text to the console. If you want to display text on a pygame window, you have to use a `font` object and its `render` method.

Answer (score 0):

pythons PRINT function only ever outputs to the console.

For pygame you will need to look at pygame.font

It wont let me post a link, But do a quick google search for "pygame.font" or "text in pygame" and you'll be in the right direction.

Also, with a lot of GUI toolkits like pygame or tkinter, it is important to remember that everything is done INSIDE a loop. Your basic code structure will look like this:

setup

while True:

```
     game logic

     draw the screen (back to front)
```

So in your code a black background is drawn continuously and nothing else ever happens because your loop never ends.

For this specific case, it makes a lot more sense to have your game just be console game. Pygame is great if you want to make a 2D animated game (think pong, pokemon etc) or need sound.

In any case, try copying all of your game logic into the while loop, run it, and look around for a terminal.  That isn't a solution, but you should see what is going on.  Hope that helps.